# How to truncate the second column from a dot (.)?

Tags: bash, awk

INPUT:

```
10.175.192.16   vgxyxgf.de.foo.net  asdf    34efg
10.175.192.17   sdtds.de.foo.net    xyyxv   e5432
10.175.243.20   asdfycfb.us.foo.net dfvasf  34525
```

OUTPUT:

```
10.175.192.16   vgxyxgf
10.175.192.17   sdtds
10.175.243.20   asdfycfb
```

How can I make the OUTPUT? Like "awk '{SOMEMAGIC}' foo.txt

So I have the "INPUT" and I need a /etc/hosts file style OUTPUT... :\

Comment: Can you clarify your question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `awk`

```
awk '{sub(/\..*/,"",$2);$0=$1 "  "$2}1' foo.txt
```

With `sed`

```
sed 's/^\(\([^.]*\.\)\{4\}\).*$/\1/;s/\.$//' foo.txt
```

Comment: I don't know how it works... but it work!! wow..

Comment: @LanceBaynes Magic of course!  What I did was replace everything after the first dot in the 2nd field `$2` with a null string. I then told `awk` that the current line `$0` is only made up of the first field `$1` followed by two spaces followed by the (altered) second field `$2`

Answer (score 8):

Just for fun, here's a non-`awk`, non-`sed` answer:

```
cut -f1-4 -d. foo.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Another awk solution, analogous to [Steven's `cut` answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/30028/4667):

```
awk -F. -v OFS=. '{print $1, $2, $3, $4}' filename
```

Uses dots as the field separator, and prints the first 4 fields dot-separated.